Deriving the total angular momentum operator $\hat{\vec{L}}^2$
In Bohmian mechanics, the operators for physical observables can be derived really naturally by calculating the average physical quantity. It is possible for example to derive the average angular momentum of the bohmian particles of a given wave function:
$$\langle L_x\rangle=\langle yp_z-zp_y\rangle=\int \psi^*\left[y \mathfrak{Im}\left(\frac{\partial_z\psi}{\psi}\right)-z\mathfrak{Im}\left(\frac{\partial_y\psi}{\psi}\right)\right]\psi dV$$
Here we have used the guiding equation which tells us the momentum of the bohmian particle:
$$\vec{p}=\hbar \mathfrak{Im}\left(\frac{\vec{\nabla}\psi}{\psi}\right)$$
Looking at the first term:
\begin{align}
\int \psi^*\left(y\frac{\hbar}{2i}\frac{\psi^*\partial_z\psi-\psi\partial_z\psi^*}{\psi \psi^*}\right)\psi dV&=\frac{\hbar}{2i}\int y\left(\psi^*\partial_z\psi-\psi\partial_z\psi^*\right) dV\\&= \frac{\hbar}{2i}\int y\left(\psi^*\partial_z\psi-\psi\partial_z\psi^* -\psi^*\partial_z\psi+\psi^*\partial_z\psi\right) dV\\&= \frac{\hbar}{2i}\int 2y\psi^*\partial_z\psi  \ dV \  -\frac{\hbar}{2i}\int y\partial_z(\psi \psi^*)dV\\&= \int\psi^*(-i\hbar y\frac{\partial}{\partial z})\psi \ dV-\frac{\hbar}{2i}\int_{S_{xy}}y\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\partial_z(\psi^*\psi)dzdS_{xy}\\&=\int\psi^*(-i\hbar y\frac{\partial}{\partial z})\psi \ dV \\&= \langle \psi|-yi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial z}|\psi\rangle
\end{align}
Analogously for the second term we have:
$$\langle \psi|-zi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|\psi\rangle$$
So finally the average value of $L_x$ is given by:
$$\langle L_x\rangle=\langle \psi|-yi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-(-zi\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial y})|\psi\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{y}\hat{p_z}-\hat{z}\hat{p_y}|\psi\rangle := \langle\psi|\hat{L_x}|\psi\rangle$$
So we see that such defined operator of angular momentum can represent the average angular momentum of the wave function (in Copenhagen terms) or the average angular momentum of an ensemble of Bohmian particles guided by that wave function. In such a way we can derive the position, momentum and Hamiltionian operators.
My question is about deriving the operator, corresponding to the squared magnitude of the angular momentum: $|\vec{L}|^2=L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2$ and I want to prove that the average of that quantity is given by $$\langle\psi|\hat{L_x}^2+\hat{L_y}^2+\hat{L_z}^2|\psi \rangle$$
but when I try to do this using the method I showed for the angular momentum, I get really cumbersome long integrals and get stuck. Can you derive it? Is there a simpler way maybe (assuming we have the other operators given)?
